# Corona SDK - Touch does not end when dragged offscreen/off grid of buttons

Tags: coronasdk

I setup a grid wherein the user touches one and moves through the grid.

The problem is that when the touch goes beyond the grid or beyond the screen, the touch does not end.

Do note that the grid is made up of individual square "buttons" that change color when the user drags their finger over them.

How do I fix this so the touch ends when it leaves the screen or leaves the grid?

Thanks for the help!

Regards,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to have already been answered here:

[How do I detect a TouchOut event in Corona SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215880/how-do-i-detect-a-touchout-event-in-corona-sdk)

And here:

[touchEvent for Grid(2D-Array)of Sprites using Corona sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318503/touchevent-for-grid2d-arrayof-sprites-using-corona-sdk)

If you need more help, please post your code so it's easier to help you.